# 404 error when installing gcc in Ubuntu 18.04 Windows 10

Tags: apt, windows-10, gcc

When I attempt to do `sudo apt install gcc` in Ubuntu 18.04 running in Windows 10, I get the error message

> Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1
>    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

In addition to several other very similar messages. I have tried disabling my firewall, but that doesn't help.  I was able to successfully get libxpm-dev, so I don't think it is a complete inability to install anything.  Any suggestions of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you remember to do `sudo apt update` first - to make sure the repository information is up to date?

Comment: I think so, but I will try this.

Comment: Doing the `sudo apt update` worked.  Thank you very much.